# Memory problems when working with images and camera on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, didreceivememorywarning, memory-warning

In my application users can add up to 8 images taken by the camera and upload them to the server one-by-one.
My problem is that even when taking the first picture i get an memory warning, which of course forces the app to release any view not visible.

What is the best practice approach to handling pictures?
How do I hold them until they're uploaded, without running out of memory?

My objective is to avoid any memory warnings.

Thanks in advance.

/Esben

Comment: How do you store the images? Are you storing them as NSData? or storing them in directory. Post some code.

Comment: You know that the memory warnings are delivered pretty regularly/liberally by iOS?  Just because you get one doesn't mean the phone is out of memory.  It just means you should let go of data that's not necessary.  If you need to hold on to images past the *first* memory warning, that may just be what you need to do.

Comment: Getting the memory warnings did cause the app to release everything not in view (intended bu the framework). I fixed this ssue by reloading all views in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After clicking images store images into Document directory. It is most safe option to store

images and then use it. Find some tutorial and after click image send image to document

directory and then fetch from directory and use it. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is indeed how I solved the problem my self. Right after capture I write the captured image to the Documents folder. When I need to upload the image I read it directly from disk to request. This works Doesen't get rid of the memory warnings, but it ensures that iOS don't kill the app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed Following steps.

I am faced like this problem, now it's working for me use following steps.

1. Select image and and display to UIImageView. then Upload to server.
2. Release UIImageView.
3. Again take picture and upload to server.